# Proof of $\det\partial_2^t∂_2 =m^2 ·k(G)$ for G, finite connected graph with reduced homology being 0

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

> Let $G$ be a finite connected graph. Let $K$ be a 2-dimensional complex such that $K^{(1)} = G$, $\tilde{H}_2(K)=0$ and $\tilde{H}_1(K)=\Bbb Z_m$. Show that $\det\partial_2^t∂_2 =m^2 ·k(G).$

Over the above statement, the $\tilde{H}$ notates the reduced simplicial homology and $k(G)$ notates the number of spanning trees of given graph G.

I can't figure out where to start to prove the square of boundary operator results to be same as $m^2\cdot k(G)$?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from Remark 4.17 / Proposition 4.10 of ["Cuts and flows of cell complexes"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10801-014-0561-2) by Duval, Klivans and Martin. Their formula (as applied to your problem, by taking $\Sigma=\Upsilon=K$) states:

$$
\det(\partial^t_2\partial_2)=\sum_\Gamma |\mathbf{T}(\tilde H_{1}(K,\Gamma))|^2.
$$

Here $\mathbf{T}(\cdot)$ denotes the torsion subgroup and the sum over $\Gamma$ runs over all "relatively acyclic" subcomplexes of $K$ (Definition 3.1). Since $\tilde{H}_1(K)$ is torsion, the discussion before Proposition 3.2 shows that the $\Gamma$ are in fact the spanning trees of $G$.

Furthermore, the relative homology groups $\tilde{H}_1(K,\Gamma)$ are all isomorphic to $\tilde{H}_1(K)=\mathbb{Z}_m$ because all the $\Gamma$'s are trees and hence contractible. The result is that the sum evaluates to $m^2 k(G)$ as desired.

---

Here follow a few general comments. The above formula is an interesting higher-dimensional variant of the [Kirchhoff Matrix-Tree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) which expresses the number of spanning trees of a graph in terms of the determinant of the "up-down" Laplacian $L^{ud}=\partial\partial^t$ (with a row and vertex removed). Contrast this with the "down-up Laplacian" $L^{du}=\partial_i^t\partial_i$ that's considered here. These two matrices are closely related (physicists might call them "supersymmetric partners") since the multisets of their nonzero eigenvalues are identical. However, it seems that $L^{ud}$ shows up more frequently in practice and hence is much more studied. I could be showing my ignorance but other than the above formula, I haven't seen much else on $L^{du}$ in the literature.

The "up-down / down-up" terminology can be found in Duval, Klivans and Martin's [survey on simplicial and cellular trees](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06819) which includes several higher-dimensional generalizations of Kirchhoff (all involving $L^{ud}$ though!).

Comment: from the lecture note of the class of algebraic topology recommended to handle with.

Comment: In your link there's no proposition 4.11 only 4.1 exist.

Comment: Sorry, Prop. 4.11 was a typo for Prop. 4.10, as cited in Remark 4.17. This is quite a nice problem: which lecture notes by which professor?

Comment: why is it so good? I even don't reach the level to check how good it is. There's another pb set from the professor: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804986/what-is-basic-bond-and-hows-it-defined-in-terms-of-spanning-tree

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78346/algebraic-topology 
will you come in here?

Comment: and, the additional pb set.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804971/if-%CF%83%E2%88%88k-and-%CF%83-v-0-v-1-v-i-%E2%88%88-c-%E2%88%82t-%CF%83-sum-v-in-lk-sigma-0